# Get array of list and keep reference?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, reference

For some performance reason , I want to get array of List directly in C#

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,2765070d40f47b98

My code here:

```
private UIVertex[] GetArray(List<UIVertex> verts)
    {
        var aryF = typeof(List<UIVertex>).GetField("_items", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        return aryF.GetValue(verts) as UIVertex[];
    }

private void SetSize(List<UIVertex> list, int size)
{
        sizeF = typeof(List<UIVertex>).GetField("_size", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
}

static List<UIVertex> verts
static UIVertex[] ary;
//...
ary = GetArray(verts);
```

In my case I can reuse 'verts' , But when 'verts' count change. my ary need to get again ( and it call reflection ) ,

reflection cost is too height , Can I just keep ary reference ? How to do it?

PS:

When I use `List.Add` or `List.Get` , It's trigger `String.memcpy()` , It's too slow , It is why I want to use array directly.
And bacause I reuse List , so array Length not change uaually. I can just keep it reference to be fast.

PS 2.

here is modify before:

```
static List<T> Orgin = new List<T>(128);
void DO() // *it call a lot of times.*
{
    GetListByAPI(Orgin);// here is API , So it must insert List<T>.
    int Size = Orgin.Count() * 5; // size is unchanged in here.
    if(Orgin.Capacity < Size) 
    {
        Orgin.Capacity = Size;
    }
    for(int i = Orgin.Count() ; i < Size ;i++)
    {
        T t
        Orgin.Add(t);// I need "Oring.Count() * 5 " Size Array for my logic.
        //...
    }
}
```

here is modify after :

```
static List<T> Orgin = new List<T>(128);
static T[] StaticAry;
void DO() // *it call a lot of times.*
{
    bool LastOringCapacity = Orgin.Capacity;
    GetListByAPI(Orgin);// here is API , So it must insert List<T>.

    bool arrayRefChanged = Orgin.Capacity > LastOringCapacity ; // I Can know it. and get array again. 

    int Size = Orgin.Count() * 5; // size is unchanged in here.
    SetSize(Oring, Size);//here set array legth of list by refection
    StaticAry = GetArray(Orgin);//here I get array of list by reflection
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        T t = StaticAry[i];//just use it , avoid to use List.Add api. 
        //....
    }
}
```

this static Orgin is reuse , So Oring.Capacity maybe not change. So array of Orgin is not resize too. And I want to get array adress. directly use it.
But now. I need use reflection to get array in every single DO().

The complexity place is that
`List<T>.Capacity` & `Array.Length` & `List<T>.Count()` are three differet value.

Comment: There are ways to speed up reflection - yes. But it would be unwise to use reflection to get the array out of the list like that (e.g. the array may have more entries than you expect). Given you are having a perf issue, perhaps show us more context and we can provide alternatives?

Comment: When the [Capacity](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9808f1f5ef16c436) is changed, the _items is copied to new array and replaced. How are you expecting ary to handle that?

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem. can you elaborate on `some performance reason`?

Comment: Why use `List<T>` in the first place? Manage It your self by renting and copy from an ArrayPool, ect. better for your LOB, you get control over the expansion. and always have access to the array or span (pinned if need be)

Comment: @Martheen I will check Capacity changed , and get array agin , but it's almost not change in my case.
@zaitsman Because when I use `List.Add` or `List.Get` , It's trigger `String.memcpy()` , It's too slow , And I can sure my array count , So I don't need List<T> , I use List<T> just because my used API interface need it.

Comment: "but it's almost not change in my case" can you explain what this means?

Comment: @Martheen , Bacuse I reuse List<T> , so it's Capacity be bigger then count usually .

Comment: Please update the question with your full scenario

Comment: `And bacause I reuse List , so array Length not change uaually.` You said you were calling `List.Add`. How do you anticipate that working?

Comment: @mjwills I edit my question. it's so complexity , I try to explain again.

Comment: `// I need "Oring.Count() * 5 " Size Array for my logic.` Set `List.Capacity` before you start adding to it.

Comment: @mjwills I edited my question. I missing this :)

Answer (score 1):

When the `List<T>Count` has changed (the `Capacity` in fact), it is because the internal array of the list has been resized.

Resizing a larger array requires allocating a new one and copying its content and forget the old memory space.

In theory shrinking is not a problem and only requires "cutting" the array.

But due to the organization of memory's cells it is impossible to ensure a grow without using a totally new consecutive block with a full available space.

[Array.Resize(T[], Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.resize) :

> This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one. array must be a one-dimensional array.

**Thus you can't avoid that: each time the array is resized, you need to get it again.**

Therefore and unless you do such thing once time and being sure that the array's capacity does not change, I do not recommend the technique you use because it is difficult to ensure that you always have the right array and not an abandonned reference.

Thus you should use the already existing method [`List<T>.ToArray()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d4409b7542728cec).

**But in fact, and if you can, because you want speed, you should use an [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array) instead of a `List`.**

As you can see, here what the `List` does when `Capacity` or `Count` over `Capacity` changes in [List<T>.Capacity](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9808f1f5ef16c436,references) :

```
T[] newItems = new T[value];
if (_size > 0) {
    Array.Copy(_items, 0, newItems, 0, _size);
}
_items = newItems;
```

And here is the `Add` method:

```
public void Add(T item) {
  if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
  _items[_size++] = item;
  _version++;
}
```

`Array.Resize()` does the same thing:

```
if (larray.Length != newSize) {
  T[] newArray = new T[newSize];
    Array.Copy(larray, 0, newArray, 0,  larray.Length > newSize? newSize : larray.Length);
    array = newArray;
}
```

This could have been optimized for the case of downsizing I think, but there may be some reason related to CLR or GC.

Comment: Thanks your explain , very clean and detail , I think I will try to use ToArray() to compare with refelction , which is faster :)

Comment: ToArray() gives you a copy of the array like a snapshot at the time of call of the method... If you can change the type of your variable from List to an array, this is the best and steady and clean option to optimize the processings speed.